# Safe publication and ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Let's assume we have a class Container

```
class Container {
      private final Map<LongHolder, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
      static class LongHolder {
         private final Long i;
         private LongHolder(Long i) {
            this.i = i;
         }
      }

      public LongHolder createValue(Long i) {
          LongHolder v = new LongHolder(i);
          map.put(v, 1)
          return LongHolder;
      }

      public void doSmth(LongHolder longHolder) {
         map.get(longHolder);
         ... // do smth
      }
}
```

Can operations be reordered in a such manner that the reference to LongHolder from createValue escapes the method and thus becomes avaliable for other threads before putting it into the map? In this case we can acquire a LongHolder refernce form createValue and pass it to doSmth in the other thread which won't see it in the map. Is it possible? If not please explain.

Update:
The Javadoc of ConcurrentHashMap states *Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their
  onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a
  happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for
  that key reporting the updated value.)*
 But there is *of the most recently completed update operations* the
   question was exactly about this subtle case when reordering
   potentially could happen in the way that actually *update operation*
   wasn't complete and reference escaped before `put`.The Javadoc of
   `ConcurrentHashMap` states only the fact that *given key bears a
   happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key* 
   in other words only if we get retrieval for that key we can debate
   about *happens before* relations with update operation for this key.

I can only suggest few other reasons why it can't happen:

1) that the reordering rules are more strict than I thought and we can't assume an arbitral reordering(or can we? and what are the rules?).

2) that `put` has some magic properties that don't allow reodering and `return` happens only after completed `put`. What are those properties in that case?

Comment: No, it's not possible. `ConcurrentHashMap` guarantees the [Happens-before relationship](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/happens-before.html). So, as long as `put` happens before `get`, you will get consistent results.

Comment: How do you imagine it "escapes the method"? It is created there and then returned; how will another piece of code get access to it other than as a result of `createValue`, ie after it was already put in the map?

Comment: The same way it can happen during the object construction without proper synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

Let assume that threads `A` and `B` have a reference to a `Container` instance.

(Since `Container.map` is declared as `final`, its value will be safely published.  Furthermore, since it refers to a `ConcurrentHashMap`, no synchronization is required to maintain thread-safety.)

Now suppose thread `A` calls `Longholder holder = container.createValue(x)` and somehow passes `holder` to thread `B`.  Your question is, if `B` calls `doSmth` passing that holder, will the `map.get(holder)` call see it in the map?

The answer is Yes, it will.

The specification for `ConcurrentHashMap` says this:

> *"Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)"*.

That means there is a *happens before* from the `put` call that thread `A` made and the subsequent `get` call in thread `B`.  That in turn means that:

- the `get` *will* find the `LongHolder` key, and
- the `get` *will* return the correct value.

The value of the `LongHolder` object's `i` field will also be as expected, and it would be even if `LongHolder` was a *mutable* holder.

(Note that there is not much point declaring an immutable `LongHolder` here.  It is equivalent to a `java.lang.Long` ... albeit with a simpler API.)

---

> Can operations be reordered in a such manner that the reference to `LongHolder` from `createValue` escapes the method and thus becomes available for other threads before putting it into the map?

Basically, no.  The relevant operations are this:

```
      LongHolder v = new LongHolder(i);
      map.put(v, 1)
      return v;    // corrected typo
```

1. There is no reordering of the source code that makes any sense.
2. If you are talking about reordering by compiler with respect to the thread that is running `createValue`, the JLS does not permit it.   Any reordering that alters intra-thread visibility is forbidden.
3. The publication of `v` via the map is a safe publication, due to the properties of `get` and `put`.  (At the implementation, there are memory barriers that forbid the harmful reorderings around the `get` and `put` calls.)
4. and 3. are a *consequence* of the *happens before* relationships.

Now, if the code was to change to this:

```
      LongHolder v = new LongHolder(i);
      map.put(v, 1)
      // Somehow modify v.i
      return v;
```

then *that* would be a form of unsafe publication.  Since the change to `v.i` by `A` happens after the `put`, the *happens before* relation between the `put` and the `get` in `B` is no sufficient to guarantee to make the new value of `v.i` visible in thread `B`.   That is because the *chaining* doesn't work anymore.

Now, I suppose that if the result of the `createValue` call in thread `A` was passed to another thread (`B` or `C`) in an unsafe way, then the latter is not guaranteed to see the correct value for `v.i` ... if `LongHolder` is mutable.  But that is not a problem with the `createValue` / `doSmth` code.  And the publication of the value of `v` via the map is safe.

But I reckon that this discussion of reorderings is missing the point.  Any reordering that violates the visibility semantics guaranteed by the memory model is forbidden.  The JIT compiler is not allowed to do it.  So you just need to do the *happens before* analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've updated my question since the answer didn't fit to size of a comment.